# - (UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath not called

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uicollectionview

I have this two delegate:

```
#pragma mark = UICollectionViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"COUNT IS %d", [[AHImageDataSource sharedDataSource] count]);
    return [[AHImageDataSource sharedDataSource] count];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}
```

numberOfItemsInSection returned 12. but the cellForItem is not called. When I just hardcode the numberOfItemsInSection, it actually is getting called. Any idea of why this weird issue is hapening?

Here's a [sample project](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/19680269/Test.zip) demonstrating the issue

Comment: Not able to run your sample project. It is showing a blank screen always. Anything missing in that?

Comment: nope.. it's supposed to show a blank screen.. but you should put a breakpoint in cellForItem and see it doesn't get called

Comment: Ok. got it. What was that hardcode thing in numberOfItemsInSection? I tried setting 15 there and it still didnt call.

Comment: hmm..really?I tried it with 4 or basically any numbers and it is getting called

Answer (score 2):

If `[[AHImageDataSource sharedDataSource] count]` is returning `nil`, `cellForItemAtIndexPath` will not get called. So please make sure that `[[AHImageDataSource sharedDataSource] count]` has some value.

I'm not able to download your sample project, so can't help much. :(

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the delegate?..

Be sure that the method name is correct or you are missing something..

Comment: Yes.. I did, you can check the sample project if you want

Answer (score 0):

The file PintCollectionViewLayout.m was not included in the Compile Sources in the target's Build phase. Add that, resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Yup this checks out. Everything works as soon as you add PintCollectionViewLayout.m to the compile sources. If you the run app as is, it logs "Unknown class PintCollectionViewLayout in Interface Builder file". Which goes away when you've added the file to the compile sources